# How to avoid the login prompt when using Crystal reports?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a button to show another form and send parameters to a crystal report, but after I click that button it always show database login, and I have to input username and password. When I tick off "use integrated security instead" it failed.
My question is how to connect to database without showing the login?

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

Public Class param_list_agree

Private Sub Cmdpreview_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Cmdpreview.Click
    Call opendb()

    Dim cryrpt As New ReportDocument
    cryrpt.Load("D:\Report\List_Agreement.rpt")
    Dim crparamdfs As ParameterFieldDefinitions
    Dim crparamdf As ParameterFieldDefinition
    Dim crparamvl As New ParameterValues
    Dim crparamdisvl As New ParameterDiscreteValue
    Dim konek As New ConnectionInfo



    crparamdisvl.Value = DTP1.Text
    crparamdfs = cryrpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
    crparamdf = crparamdfs.Item("@date_to")
    crparamvl = crparamdf.CurrentValues

    crparamvl.Clear()
    crparamvl.Add(crparamdisvl)
    crparamdf.ApplyCurrentValues(crparamvl)

    rpt_listagree.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryrpt
    rpt_listagree.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    rpt_listagree.Show()

    'CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryrpt
    'CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    With konek
        .ServerName = "ServerName"
        .DatabaseName = "DatabaseName"
        .UserID = "UserID"
        .Password = "Password"
        .IntegratedSecurity = False
    End With
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub param_list_agree_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call opendb()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: In your code, have you tried not setting .`UserID` and `.Password`, and setting `.IntegratedSecurity = True`? Actually that seems to be redundant code, as `konek` isn't even used as far as I can  tell. Maybe that's ur problem.

Comment: We don't need to use the `Call` keyword anymore.

Comment: Its same, always show database login

Comment: Where do you set your connection string? the code `With konek
        .ServerName = "ServerName"
        .DatabaseName = "DatabaseName"
        .UserID = "UserID"
        .Password = "Password"
        .IntegratedSecurity = False
    End With' seems to be redundant, as it appears after you show your report.

Comment: call opendb() is my connection string.. its call module

Comment: It would probably help to show the code for the `opendb` method

Answer (score 1):

For starters, always set your login info before you load/set parameters. If parameters are dynamic in any way, they will try to access the database, and no login info has been set.

Anytime you get the pop-up dialogue to login, it means Crystal tried to access the database in report before the connection settings were set (or the connection info is incorrect).

*** EDIT

```
Dim cryrpt As New ReportDocument
cryrpt.Load("D:\Report\List_Agreement.rpt")
Dim crparamdfs As ParameterFieldDefinitions
Dim crparamdf As ParameterFieldDefinition
Dim crparamvl As New ParameterValues
Dim crparamdisvl As New ParameterDiscreteValue
Dim konek As New ConnectionInfo

'Login FIRST
With konek
    .ServerName = "ServerName"
    .DatabaseName = "DatabaseName"
    .UserID = "UserID"
    .Password = "Password"
    .IntegratedSecurity = False
End With

'THEN set your parameters
crparamdisvl.Value = DTP1.Text
crparamdfs = cryrpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
crparamdf = crparamdfs.Item("@date_to")
crparamvl = crparamdf.CurrentValues

crparamvl.Clear()
crparamvl.Add(crparamdisvl)
crparamdf.ApplyCurrentValues(crparamvl)

rpt_listagree.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryrpt
rpt_listagree.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
rpt_listagree.Show()

'CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryrpt
'CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

Comment: Thanks john, but where I need put the set login, and like what script that I use?? please give me example with script the above

Comment: There's more to it than just that code. My point was you need to login first. I'm not writing all of the code from start-to-finish.